# $_GET not working 30

Tags: php, get

I have a PHP page(PAGE a) which is embedded(included) another PHP(Page b). It contains a Calendar. I am trying to create a functionality where when the user clicks on a link of a Date, the URL gets redirected to the PHP page b. I have tried to pass the Date through the URL and retrieve it on the Page b using $_GET. But the $_GET[] does not give me the value though the URL shows the value of the date.

Is it necessary to wrote the $_GET code inside the FORM in page b????

Is there something that I am doing wrong? Please help.

here is code of Page a:

```
<br><p><a href = 'add_eventec.php?selDate = $selDate' >Add Event</p><br />
```

Code of Page b:

```
if (!empty( $_GET['selDate']) ){

                $selcDate = $_GET['selDate'];
                echo "This is ". $selcDate;
                //$selDate = $_GET['dateSel'];
            }else{

                echo "This is not workingggggg";
            }
```

Please let me know.

---Worked finally!!!

Comment: What' s the error? What is getting displayed? More info plz.

Comment: please `var_dump($_GET)` so we have an idea what you recieve.
A first glance guess: `add_eventec.php?selDate = $selDate` - html does not support variables.

Comment: First, replace the anchor with `<a href="add_eventec.php?selDate=<?=$selDate?>" >Add Event</a>`, see if that helps

Answer (score 3):

I could be wrong but spaces in your URL count as characters too.
Re-format your URL to not have the spaces:

```
<br><p><a href = 'add_eventec.php?selDat=' . $selDate >Add Event</p><br />
```

Also note that when building URLs I try to avoid adding variables into the string- I concatenate. It is safer.

Lastly, the code above- is it inside an echo statement? If not it needs to be:

```
<br><p><a href = 'add_eventec.php?selDat=<?php echo $selDate;?>'>Add Event</p><br />
```

Answer (score 1):

Code should be

```
<?php
echo "<br><p><a href='add_eventec.php?selDate=$selDate'>Add Event</p><br />";
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
if (isset($_GET['selDate'])) {
```

And if that doesn't work selDate probably isn't passing.

Try

```
print_r($_GET);
```

to check if it is

Answer (score 0):

```
<br><p><a href = 'add_eventec.php?selDate = $selDate' >Add Event</p><br />
```

Try removing the spaces so it becomes

```
<br><p><a href = "add_eventec.php?selDate=$selDate" >Add Event</p><br />
```

Comment: that code is a part of the entire page. The single quotes are because the page is a part of ECHO.

Answer (score 0):

You need to enclose your $selDat variable in php tags so that it gets echoed in the HTML.

`<a href = 'add_eventec.php?selDate=<?= $selDate ?>' >Add Event</a>`

Answer (score 0):

this will not collect php variable,as this is only html ,you have to explicitly render your date var in php

```
<br><p><a href = 'add_eventec.php?selDate = $selDate' >Add Event</p><br />
```

you can try these 2 methods->
1.

```
<br><p><a href = 'add_eventec.php?selDate=<?php echo $selDate ?>' >Add Event</p><br />
```

2.

```
<?php
echo "<br><p><a href = 'add_eventec.php?selDate = $selDate' >Add Event</p><br />";
?>
```

Comment: I try doing No 1.
 <br><p><a href = 'add_eventec.php?selDate = <?php echo $selDate ?>' >Add Event</p><br />
On doing that... The $_GET empty is true. It does not work. So basically, the values are not being received on tha actual PHP page but it still shows up in the url like this: http://......add_eventec.php?selDate%20=14-6-2013